# If $H$ and $Z$ are closed subgroups generating $G$, is $H \times Z \rightarrow G$ an open map?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff topological group with center $Z$ and closed subgroup $H$.  Suppose that $H.Z = G$.  Is the product map

$$H \times Z \rightarrow G$$

necessarily an open map?  That is, can we identify with $G$ as a quotient group of $H \times Z$?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by $H.Z=G$?

Comment: $HZ$ is the group generated by $H$ and $Z$.  It is equal to the product set $\{ hz : h \in H, z \in Z \}$.

Comment: I believe this is a counter-example. Take $G=GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, then the center $Z=\{\lambda I:\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^\star\}$. Take $H=SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ this is a closed subgroup of $G$ (As it is the inverse of $\{1\}$ under the continuous map $\det:GL_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\star$). Clearly every matrix can be divided by it's determinant (or some root of it) and therefore $H\cdot Z =G$.

It is left to show that $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not a quotient of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})\times\mathbb{R}^\star$. I believe this is true (isn't it?)

Comment: I don't think this is a counterexample.  $$GL_2 \cong \frac{SL_2 \times Z}{K}$$ as group schemes, where $K = \pm I$, so passing to $\mathbb{R}$-rational points we get a quotient of topological spaces.